# Add text before specific characters

Tags: vb.net

`str as String = " " +"thisrocks" + " "`

and `strArray(0) = 123456sdv   :'++':`

so i want to add str before the :'++':, and then

`strArray(0) =  123456sdv   thisrocks :'++':`

Is it possible ?
What could I do to search for it ? Regex maybe ?

str and strArray will already be there from previous codes. I just want to combine it int he right place.

Using the space in between will not be helpful as the strArray(0) could also be,  `dsf dsv dsgvsvs svs svssd bdsb      sbdfb bsbb    sb s          sbsfbfsbsbfs  :'++':` and so on.

I can't control it as they come like that from previous codes and there is no way to fix them :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't generalize the question since it is not clear enough, for this occasion you can use the following code to insert a string in between these two words

```
Dim str As String = " " + "thisrocks" + " " 
Dim strArray(10) As String
strArray(0) = "123456sdv   :'++':"
strArray(0) = strArray(0).Replace(":'++':", str & ":'++':")
```

Output will be

`"123456sdv    thisrocks :'++':"`

**Note:**
this will work as, replace `:'++':`  with `& str` and add `:'++':` to it so `:'++':` will stay their for the next replacement.

Comment: ok that was a easy way of doing it, why the hell didn't I think of it before :O

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.IndexOf to find where the marker `:'++':` is and String.Insert to insert the required data:

```
Dim sample As String = "123456sdv :'++':"

Dim insertData As String = " thisrocks "
Dim marker As String = ":'++':"
Dim insertPos As Integer = sample.IndexOf(marker)
If insertPos >= 0 Then
    sample = sample.Insert(insertPos, insertData)
End If

Console.WriteLine(sample) ' outputs "123456sdv  thisrocks :'++':"
```